# Kann ein Substantiv in einer Satzreihe gleichzeitig Subjekt und Objekt sein?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammatical-case

Gegeben sei folgender Satz:

> Diese Funktion nennen wir Transferfunktion und ist definiert wie in (1).

Offensichtlich ist dies eine Satzreihe aus zwei Sätzen:

> Diese Funktion nennen wir Transferfunktion.

und

> Diese Funktion ist definiert wie in (1).

Nun ist *Diese Funktion* im einen Satz aber Objekt und im anderen Subjekt. Nichtsdestotrotz wird sie im zweiten Satz ausgelassen. Ist dies zulässig?

Comment: "Diese Funktion nennen wir Transferfunktion und sie ist definiert wie in (1)." ist m.E. richtig, aber da ich keine Regel dazu benennen kann, nur ein Kommentar. "Diese Funktionen nennen wir TF und sind abgebildet auf Seite 3" - da würde ich auf Seite 3 ein Foto der Autoren erwarten. :)

Comment: @userunknown Ich erwarte dagegen ein Foto der Funktionen. Anders, wenn der Satz "Wir nennen diese Funktionen TF..." lauten würde.

Comment: Gleichzeitig Subjekt und Objekt geht auf keinen Fall. Es ist höchstens so, dass eine Wiederholung auch weggelassen werden kann, wenn der grammatische Fall zwar nicht identisch, die Form jedoch identisch ist. Der Hörer/Leser wird es sicherlich verstehen, und ob es guter Stil ist, ist sowieso immer Ansichtsfrage. Meinem Sprachgefühl nach muss ein "sie" stehen.

Comment: Meiner Ansicht nach ist die Funktion das passive Subjekt des Satzes (vgl. Englisch *subject* i.S.v. Unterrichtsstoff): "Diese funktion heißt TF und (ist) definiert ...". Damit sprechen *wir* wenigstens nicht mehr so viel ueber uns, obwohl der Bezug zu *uns* sowieso implizit klar ist. Ist das vielleicht eine Frage der Aufmerksamkeit, den Gegenüber mit Personalpronom anzusprechen?

Comment: @vectorious Die Frage war nicht, wie der Satz umformuliert werden könnte. Grammatikalisch ist das *wir* eindeutig das Subjekt im ersten Teilsatz.

Comment: Natuerlich war die Frage ob der Satz umformuliert werden muss. Grammatik hat auch eine semantische Funktion. Das heißt, der Satz kann objektiv oder subjektiv formuliert werden. Daher auch die Bezeichnung *Satzgegenstand*, die nicht immer mit dem grammatikalischen Begriff *Subjekt* übereinstimmt.

Comment: @vectorious Ich komme nicht ganz dahinter, wie diese Ausführungen bei der Beantwortung der Frage weiterhelfen. Mir geht es nicht um die Semantik, die ist unstreitig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das kann zum Teil eine Geschmacks- bzw. Stilfrage sein. Wer jedoch nach 'Zulässigkeit' fragt, will eine Regel, am besten aus einer Grammatik. Nun ist es mit den grammatischen Regeln so eine Sache: Nicht alle Regeln werden von allen akzeptiert, womit wir doch wieder bei so etwas wie Stilfragen wären.

Wie auch immer: Auch und gerade Grammatiker greifen gerne zu einem psychologischen Trick, den Goethe so beschrieb: *Denn eben, wo Begriffe fehlen, da stellt ein Wort zur rechten Zeit sich ein.* Hat man erst einmal ein Wort gefunden, am besten ein möglichst gelehrt oder kompliziert klingendes (früher lateinisch und griechisch, heute gerne englisch), dann hört sich das zumindest mal nach was an. Auch zum Thema hier wurde bereits einiges terminologische (oder 'terminologisches'?) Pulver verschossen: Ellipse, Syllepse, Zeugma, Gapping und aha!: [Subjektbinnenellipse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjektbinnenellipse). Das trifft zwar nicht exakt die hier gestellte Frage, aber es gibt die eine oder andere Ähnlichkeit. So wird etwa diskutiert, ob

> Den modischen Rock sah die fröhliche Studentin und kaufte ihn

oder auch

> Aus Baden kommt dieser Wein und schmeckt mir

möglich sind. Sie werden in dem verlinkten Wikipedia-Artikel als zulässig vorgestellt. Beide finde ich leicht irritierend, irgendetwas stört mich, obwohl hier sogar die syntaktische Funktion der Auslassung im Zweitsatz mit der des Erstsatzes übereinstimmt. Es geht jeweils um das Subjekt, welches allerdings im Vorgängersatz nicht in der Neutralposition, sondern hinter dem finiten Verb steht, ein im Deutschen überaus häufiger Satzbau.

Ich lerne daraus: Selbst wenn irgendwo geschrieben stünde, dass ein Satz nach irgendwelchen Regeln zulässig ist, muss dieser Satz nicht meinem Bedürfnis nach einem wohlgestalteten Satz entsprechen. Ich muss das letztlich selbst entscheiden. Ich kann hier nur den Vor-Postern recht geben: Ich würde es anders formulieren, entweder mit expliziter Nennung des Subjektpronomens in Satz 2, oder durch Ersetzung des Verbs *nennen* in Satz 1 durch *heißen* mit entsprechender syntaktischer Anpassung. Der angefragte Satz ist stilistisch ziemlich auf der Kippe, gut möglich, dass er ungrammatisch ist.

Aber jetzedle: Die Duden-Grammatik (Ausgabe 2016) meint dazu auf Seite 912 unter Randziffer 1416 (in Kapitel "4.3.1 Einsparungen in gereihten Sätzen"):

> (vii) Eingesparte Nominalphrasen müssen denselben Kasus aufweisen.  Andernfalls sind sie zu wiederholen. Das gilt auch dann, wenn die Kasus äußerlich nicht unterscheidbar sind:
>
> ```
>     Diese Bücher (= Nom.) interessieren mich und ich würde sie (= Akk.) gerne
>     kaufen. (*Diese Bücher interessieren mich und _ würde ich gerne kaufen.) 
>
>     Das sind die Bücher, die (= Nom.) mich interessieren und die (= Akk.)
>     ich gerne kaufen würde. (*Das sind die Bücher, die mich interessieren
>     und _ ich gerne kaufen würde.)
>
>     Das waren Menschen, die uns (= Dativ) ablehnend gegenüberstanden, ja
>     uns (= Akk.) hassten. (*Das waren Menschen, die uns ablehnend
>     gegenüberstanden, ja _ hassten.)
> ```

(*farbliche Hervorhebungen von mir weggelassen*)

Geht doch!

Comment: Heideblitz, da muss ich nach fünf Jahren doch nochmal diese Bachelorarbeit rauskramen und nachkorrigieren :)

Answer (score 8):

Ich denke, hier handelt es sich um eine (eher unfreiwillige oder unbeabsichtigte) Form eines *Zeugma* im Sinne des berühmten Zitats

> Ich heiße nicht nur Heinz Erhardt, sondern Sie auch herzlich willkommen!

oder

> Ich fror vor mich hin, denn nicht nur meine Mutter, auch der Ofen war ausgegangen

D.h. die Wiederverwendung eines Satzteiles in u.U. widersprüchlichem Sinn bzw. nicht übereinstimmender Form.

Comment: Zeugma musste ich nachschlagen, aber das scheint sich ja eher auf die Auslassung von Verben zu beziehen – sei es nun im ernsten oder im gewollt widersprüchlichen Sinn. Es fällt mir schwer, hier die Gemeinsamkeit zu erkennen – das Zeugma zielt auf unterschiedliche Bedeutungen eines Wortes ab, während hier die Bedeutung dieselbe bleibt, nur der Kasus wechselt.

Comment: @flyx Im engeren Sinn stimmt das mit der "Wiederverwendung des Prädikats". Im heute gebrauchten weiteren Sinn wird der Begriff des Zeugmas aber auch auf alle anderen (evtl. "mißbräuchlich") wiederverwendeten Satzkomponenten angewendet.

Comment: *Zeugma: syntaktisch oder semantisch ungleichartige Beziehung eines Satzgliedes, **meist** des Prädikats, auf zwei (oder mehr) andere Satzglieder (z. B. nimm dir Zeit und nicht das Leben!; sie reist mit Ehemann und Regenschirm)*

Answer (score 3):

Solche Sätze kommen in Schriftstücken wie Briefen, besonders auch Geschäftskorrespondenz sowie Behördendokumenten aus älterer Zeit (Ende 19./Anfang 20. Jahrhundert) recht häufig vor. Sie sind aber schon früh als gruselig schlechter Stil kritisiert worden. Siehe z.B. Ludwig Reiners' "Stilfibel" von 1951 Danach wurden sie seltener.

Gutes Deutsch wäre:

> Diese Funktion nennen wir Transferfunktion. Sie ist definiert wie in (1).

Lesetip:

Ludwig Reiners: Stilfibel. Der sichere Weg zum guten Deutsch. München 1951, dtv. - Mit vielen amüsanten Übungen, bei denen man miserable Sätze aus dem Kanzleideutsch oder aus schwülstiger Prosa in etwas Vernünftiges, Leichtfüßiges umwandeln soll.

Answer (score 3):

Ludwig Reiners Stilfibel ist insofern ein guter Hinweis, als dieses Werk nur ganz bestimmte Stilblüten zwingend vorschreibt. Für eine demgegenüber ernsthafte Auseinandersetzung mit dem Thema ist [Ein klassisches Zeugma](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/kraus/sprache/chap014.html) (Karl Kraus, "Die Fackel") schon eher anzuraten, wo auch das klassische

> Was heißt und zu welchem Ende studiert man Universalgeschichte?

(der Titel der Antrittsvorlesung Schillers in Jena) abgehandelt wird.

Answer (score 2):

Der Satz ist nicht korrekt. Auch wenn "diese Funktion" für beide Satzteile passt, ist sie im ersten Teil Akkusativ-Objekt und im zweiten Subjekt, und das passt nicht zusammen.

Alternativ-Formulierungen:

> Diese Funktion nennen wir Transferfunktion, und **sie** ist definiert wie in
> (1).

Korrekt, der Bezug auf das Akkusativ-Objekt wird mit "sie" hergestellt. (Das Komma ist optional, war in alter Rechtschreibung verpflichtend.)

> Diese Funktion **wird** Transferfunktion **genannt** und ist definiert wie in
> (1).

Korrekt, "diese Funktion" ist jetzt Subjekt des ersten Teils, dann passt der zweite Teil.

> Diese Funktion nennen wir Transferfunktion und definieren **sie** wie in
> (1).

Auch wenn im zweiten Teil "diese Funktion" ein Akkusativ-Objekt darstellt wie im ersten, darf das nicht ersatzlos entfallen, sondern muss durch "sie" ersetzt werden. Was in diesem Satz wegfällt, ist das gemeinsame Subjekt "wir".